# Test SWF full screen w/ Flash CC/Animate CC

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, flash-cs6, animate-cc

When pressing CTRL+ENTER to test the SWF the generated HTML seems to always use pixel in size format. I'd like the HTML to use a percentage say 100% in format, so that I could test the SWF full-screen. Is this possible? I'm using Animate CC.

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: Show your html code so we can show you what/how to fix. Use **[Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38422151/edit)** to update your question.

Comment: I know how to edit the HTML code to fix this. The problem is that everytime I press CTRL+ENTER in the IDE to test the code the compiler/IDE overwrites the HTML.

Comment: If the compiler is overwriting the HTML, you're likely editing the wrong file.  I haven't used Flash in a while, but they often had a template HTML file that you could edit. This template was used to generate the HTML file you speak of...

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I think you're right. I probably should use a separate HTML instead of the generated one to handle this issue.